# Chrome crashes when try to use spell checker to correct the spelling of words in a Vaadin text field

Tags: google-chrome, vaadin, spell-checking, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

When I try to use Google Chrome's spell checker to correct the spelling of words in a text field or text area, Chrome crashes and displays the **“Aw, Snap!”** error message. This issue is only present on Chrome.
This is the [sample code for reproducing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjweo.jpg) the issue.
As soon as I right click on the [red underlined word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qrrec.jpg), Chrome crashes and it displays the [error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjNIh.jpg). If there are multiple misspelled words in text field, only the last word causing an issue. I don’t have any issue with using spell checker for other words expect the last one, “mssage” [in this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrQ2J.jpg). I also don’t have any issue when there is another correctly spelled word after the misspelled word. In this case, it doesn’t crash.

In general, what I observed is that if the misspelled word is the last word in the text field, then the crash occurs; otherwise, it works as expected. I have checked all log files including Chrome local logs, but there is no log message related to this issue, and I am not able to debug it. I found a few partial solutions, but still couldn’t understand the root cause of this issue.

**Partial solution-1:** If we remove the text from the Button, the issue is resolved. [As you can see,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM322.jpg)  the button doesn’t have any text written on it, and in this case, it works as expected.

**Partial solution-2:** If we swap the order of the Button and Text Field, the issue is resolved. When I add components to the layout, the order makes a difference. When the button is added before the text field, [the issue isn't there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf9no.jpg).

**Partial solution-3:** This is the solution I am currently using since the first 2 solutions require me to change my layout. If I [add the suffix (sample code included)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEjnH.jpg) to the text field, [the issue is resolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtUyG.jpg); however, the suffix has to have text in it, otherwise it doesn’t solve the issue. I added Label with “.” and set opacity to “0” to make it invisible on the user end.

Thank you so much.

Comment: If a program crashes on input, is this the fault of the program or the fault of the input? IMHO this should end up as a ticket against Chrome. And if they tell you, that crashing for that input is an intended behaviour, then make it a ticket for Vaadin. But most likely this is a bug with Chrome or the libraries involved of your OS.

Comment: This IS a bug in Chrome, if a webbrowser crashes due to some input, then the validation is not done properly in chrome. I suggest opening a bug in the chrom bug tracker https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list oder https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue in Chrome Version 91.0.4472.114 in macOS and it works after upgrading to Version 92.0.4515.107.
It was already reported in [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1230127) and it's fixed in latest Chrome.